# MySql migrations with Sequelize CLI. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I want to migrate this column:

```
countryId: {
   type: Sequelize.DataTypes.CHAR(2),
   allowNull: true,
   references: {
    model: 'country',
    key: 'country_code'
   },
   field: 'country_id'
},
```

country_code:

```
countryCode: {
  type: DataTypes.CHAR(2),
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true,
  field: 'country_code'
},
```

Full console.log:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `address` (`address_id` BIGINT NOT NULL
 auto_increment , `state_id` INTEGER(11) UNIQUE, `country_id` CHAR(2), 
 PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`), FOREIGN KEY (`state_id`) REFERENCES 
`province` (`province_id`), FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES 
`country` (`country_code`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

But I get

> ERROR: Cannot add foreign key constraint

When I add `unique: true` to `country_id`, it still doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set up your associations manually using the command described herein:
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html